# What is the C-value on rechargable batteries?

Tags: batteries

On rechargable batteries, I found a specification which said something like "15 C". Up to now, I thought it would mean "15 cells". But when I saw this battery:[image: Battery] I was sure it couldn't be the amount of cells because it is so small. :D

On another forum, I they said it is some kind of factor that says how much current it can provide. I find that rather unclear. So what does "15 C" mean?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Probably max discharge rate. "C" means capacity, so in your case 4.5mAh. So 15C would be 15*4.5=67.5mA max discharge current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to TomCarpenter's comment, I found the answer:
Except from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_%28electricity%29#C_rate):

> The C-rate is a measure of the rate at which a battery is being discharged. It is defined as the discharge current divided by the theoretical current draw under which the battery would deliver its nominal rated capacity in one hour. A 1C discharge rate would deliver the battery's rated capacity in 1 hour. A 2C discharge rate means it will discharge twice as fast (30 minutes).

Hence my battery is capable of discharging as fast as 1/15 of an hour.